# Azure CloudQueue PeekMessage get invisible Messages

Tags: azure, azure-storage

According to this documentation : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storageclient.cloudqueue.peekmessage.aspx

> Only messages that are visible may be retrieved with PeekMessage.

My question is there a way to Peek a Message that has its visibility set to hidden?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Once queue message visibility property is set to  hidden, you will not be able to view the same messages until the hidden timeout expires.